# Css align tag a inside li, vertical menu

Tags: html, css

How to make vertical and horizontal align `middle` of tag `a` inside `li`? Why `vertical-align:middle;` inside `ul` `li` does not work? What is better to use `padding` or `vertical-align`?

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.col1{
 width:150px;
 border:solid;
 height:750px;
 display:table;
}
ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
ul li{
 list-style:none;
 height:40px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col1">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">Items</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `<ul>`. The reason it will work is because the parent of `<ul>` has its display set to `display: table;` Children will respond to `vertical: align center;` if their display value is set to `table-cell`. Also notice that we're positioning the `<ul>` itself and not the individual `<li>`s.

```
ul {
  ...
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also, consider setting `.col1`'s height to `100vh` instead of a hard-coded pixel value.

```
.col1 {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
}
```

To vertically align the anchor inside of each individual list item, we add the following:

```
ul li {
  ...
  position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/jqdwqG

Comment: When making code snippets, try using one that does not auto save new edits. Like codepen.

Comment: But how to make vertical align middle of tag a inside li? Bacuse now it's placed top.

Comment: I updated the demo and w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `vertical-align: middle` for the positioning, you can create a line-height as big as the height of the container (col1) and set the vertical-align to the ul. It works like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpzReW. However, I think Andy has a better solution.

Comment: I want to show an alternative solution. No need to downvote. I upvoted Andy's answer myself.

Answer (score -2):

you can use 
margin: 0 auto;
it will make them centered